# OCR library in React Native. Is it possible to use tesseract.js?

Tags: image, react-native, ocr, tesseract, scanning

What free library should I use to scan in React Native? I need a library to scan documents, I want to set the frame size on my camera and load data from a photo.

I found a library, but it won't be maintained anymore:
https://github.com/jonathanpalma/react-native-tesseract-ocr

Confirmation that it will no longer be supported:
https://github.com/rmtheis/tess-two

The reason why I started thinking about another library:
https://github.com/naptha/tesseract.js/issues/55

Has anyone worked with Tesseract.js on React Native or has another free and proven library?

Comment: Hi Mateusz, Could you used tesseract.js with react-native or any other way to use it?