# when i use this this library :----- react-native-tesseract-ocr 

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, reactjs

```
PS D:\OCR2>
```

### PS D:\OCR2> cd android
PS D:\OCR2\android> ./gradlew clean
FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.
1: Task failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file 'D:\OCR2\node_modules\react-native-tesseract-ocr\android\build.gradle' line: 23
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':react-native-tesseract-ocr'.

> Plugin with id 'maven' not found.

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> ==============================================================================
> **2: Task failed with an exception.**

---

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':react-native-tesseract-ocr'.

> com.android.builder.errors.EvalIssueException: compileSdkVersion is not specified. Please add it to build.gradle

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> ==============================================================================

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
  Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.
  You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.
  See https://docs.gradle.org/7.5.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
  BUILD FAILED in 6s
  5 actionable tasks: 5 up-to-date
  PS D:\OCR2\android>

Comment: Related question: [OCR library in React Native. Is it possible to use tesseract.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67970687/ocr-library-in-react-native-is-it-possible-to-use-tesseract-js)

Comment: Give me answer Not question

Comment: The comment was not for you.  It's to help other people find related questions and for the server to display related questions in the sidebar.

Comment: tell me the answer of this problem